# Prestashop model does not load data from lang table

Tags: model, prestashop, lang

I'm making a simple model in a prestashop module and I can't make it load data from the table lang.

```php
class Type extends ObjectModel
{
    /** @var int */
    public $id_type;

    /** @var varchar */
    public $titre;

    /** @var text */
    public $content;

    /** @var varchar */
    public $tags;

    public static $definition = array(
        'table' => 'type',
        'primary' => 'id_type',
        'fields' => array(
            'titre' =>              array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'required' => true, 'lang' => true),
            'content' =>                array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'required' => true, 'lang' => true),
            'tags' =>               array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'required' => true),
        ),
    );
}
```

```
database : 
ps_type [id_type, id_shop_group, id_shop, tags]
ps_type_lang [id_type, id_lang, titre, content]
```

When I load a row from the database like new Type(1); I have the tag field but not the titre and content.
Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add "multilang"

```
    public static $definition = array(
        'table' => 'type',
        'primary' => 'id_type',
        'multilang' => true,
        'fields' => array(
            'titre' =>     array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'required' => true, 'lang' => true),
            'content' =>   array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'required' => true, 'lang' => true),
            'tags' =>      array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'required' => true),
        ),
    );
```

```
$type = new Type(1, 2); // 2 is your language id
```